# Dell PR03X port replicator and DisplayPort to DVI adapter not detecting second monitor

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, dvi

I have a Dell M4400 connected to a PR03X port replicator/docking station. I use the DVI port to connect it to a first Dell 2208WFP monitor and I'm trying to use a DisplayPort-to-DVI adapter to connect it to a second Dell 2208WFP monitor.

The second monitor, connected via the DisplayPort-to-DVI adapter immediately goes into sleep mode and the laptop doesn't detect it.

What is really weird is that it did detect it the first time I plugged it in but after I unplugged the monitor and plugged it back in it stopped working. I swapped the monitors round and it detected them both but after unplugging the monitor connected via the DisplayPort-to-DVI and plugging it in again it stopped working.

Both monitors work if plugged in directly to the DVI port.

Is there some way to force re-detection? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Doh! Faulty DisplayPort-to-DVI adapter.